# How to enable / disable fast startup in Windows 10?

Tags: boot, windows-10

How to enable / disable fast startup in Windows 10?

I don't have appropriate option:

[image]

Comment: This issue is so annoying.
Even with Fast Startup disabled, it still doesn't shut down properly!

I have the same issue as you. No option.

Answer (score 8):

Write in cmd as administrator `powercfg /hibernate on` , reboot and fast startup option should appear again.

Comment: or, powercfg -h on

Answer (score 2):

Click on the "Change settings that are currently unavailable".
In the bottom of the window under "Shutdown settings" two new options appear. Now remove the tick for the option "Turn on fast startup(recommended)".
Now **Restart** the computer. (Do not shutdown. This option requires a restart to become permanent.)

Comment: Are you sure? As the OP has shown, the setting is ***absent*** from the "Shutdown settings" section (*"Turn on fast startup (recommended)"* is expected to be greyed out, not absent).

Comment: I did write this two years ago. I tested it myself before writing it here. But things have changed a lot since then. It might not be valid anymore. And I don't use windows as much to be able to test this again myself.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to the problem with Clonezilla if you see a message:

> "The image repository directory is read-only, not writalbe: /home/partimag "

Please boot your Windows again and:

- Open `cmd` as an Administrator
- Then type

  > powercfg -h off
- Go to the Windows 10 settings and look for the "Sign-in options"
- Change the checkbox to off on "Use my sign-in info to automatically finish setting up my device and repoen my apps after an update or restart."
- Power off the Windows from previously opened CMD window by writing a command:

  > shutdown -p

  or by powering it down from start menu while holding the shift button.
  (thanks to [Clonezilla creating disk image read/write issue](https://superuser.com/questions/1093740/clonezilla-creating-disk-image-read-write-issue))

After that you will be able to make a backup copy of your Windows 10 using clonezilla. Gus

Answer (score 0):

While this answer doesn't directly answer your question about "Fast Startup", I am posting this answer here because I was under the assumption that the fast startup feature was broken. Perhaps you may be also.

This was because even with fast startup disabled, everything was still open on my PC after startup.

I have since learned ([from here](https://www.tenforums.com/performance-maintenance/105074-fast-startup-issue-cant-turn-off.html)) that I was wrong, and there is another option (annoyingly) that restores all the open application's after startup.

This can be disabled from the following menu:

[image]

This is a tedious feature that has caused me to look into fast startup over and over again thinking that it was to blame for everything.