# Clonezilla creating disk image read/write issue

Tags: clonezilla

I am using clonezilla to create an disk image of my existing Windows 10 system however just after I answered yes to start the process it says:

```
-> "/home/partimage/<myImageName>".
Are you sure you want to continue? (y/n) y
The image repository directory is read-only, not writalbe: /home/partimag 
Program terminated
```

I have managed to make an image if an Windows 7 system before but now a only get the error message above.

I thought that with clonezilla the permissions of the drives are adjusted correctly for me. I would be glad if anybody could help out.

Comment: Are you sure you selected the right disk as the "image repository"? It should be the disk you want to save the image to, not the one you want to backup.

Comment: I am sure I selected the right parition. I wonder what I did wrong.

Answer (score 9):

With Win 8 (and most likely Win 10), when you do a normal shutdown, it actually does a special "fast startup" shutdown where not everything is really released so that it can boot up faster. If you hold down SHIFT when clicking the shutdown button, it will do a proper, full shutdown. You'll most likely notice this time it takes several times longer to shutdown than it previously did.

In Win 8 (and most likely Win 10), when you click restart, it does the full shutdown.

***In your case, you seem to have shutdown your system normally (resulting in 'fast startup') and hence partitions may not have been properly released. 
To avoid this, start your Windows 10 again, holding the SHIFT key down click on shutdown, which will perform complete shutdown, releasing all resources (including partitions). Now, you should be able to clone using Clonezilla.***

Comment: Please can you explain how this actually answers the question? It appear to be an answer to a different question ...

Comment: This solved the same problem that i have with my win10

Comment: The explanation was helpful, so I did a clean shutdown using cmd. I used this command "shutdown -p"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but with a drive mounted as a secondary drive. I did the "shutdown -p" from the cmd line and the clonezilla error went away.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on win 10 when trying to save a disc image to a folder located on a NTFS partition. My solution was to create another partition of exFAT type and save the image there.