# I shutdown the laptop but when I turn it on, all the programs which were open are still open

Tags: windows, windows-10, acer-aspire

It happened 2 weeks ago and still happens everytime I shutdown my laptop,when it turns on all the programs are just as i let them before shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer isnt shutting down.  It is most likely hibernating, which saves the state of your computer, then turns it off.  This allows you to turn on your computer to start up and return to that state.

These settings can be found in the Control Panel/Hardware and Sounds/Power Options.

Probably you are hitting the power button to shut down, so on the left you need to select "Choose waht the power buttone does."   Change it from "Hibernate" to "Shutdown".

Comment: I press Windows logo then go to power and select shutdown,that's how i've always shutdown my computers

Answer (score 0):

You are putting your computer to Hybrid Sleep and not shutting it down.

To fast shut down your computer, follow the procedure mentioned by Keltari.

To perform a full shutdown, type Windows Key + R to open run command and type

```
shutdown /s /t 0
```

Performing complete shutdown every time isn't recommended for computers single booting Windows 10, however, if you want to do it from within your start menu, [disable fast startup](https://superuser.com/questions/957081/how-to-enable-disable-fast-startup-in-windows-10).

To understand Hybrid Sleep, please read below.

> **Sleep Mode**
>
> Sleep mode is a power-saving state that is similar to pausing a DVD
>   movie. All actions on the computer are stopped and any open documents
>   and applications are put in memory. You can quickly resume normal,
>   full-power operation within a few seconds. Sleep mode is basically the
>   same thing as “Standby” mode.
>
> The Sleep mode is useful if you want to stop working for a short
>   period of time. The computer doesn’t use much power in Sleep mode.
>
> **Hibernate**
>
> The Hibernate mode saves your open documents and running applications
>   to your hard disk and shuts down the computer, which means once your
>   computer is in Hibernate mode, it uses zero power. Once the computer
>   is powered back on, it will resume everything where you left off.
>
> Use this mode if you won’t be using the laptop for an extended period
>   of time, and you don’t want to close your documents.
>
> **Hybrid Sleep**
>
> The Hybrid Sleep mode is a combination of the Sleep and Hibernate
>   modes meant for desktop computers. It puts any open documents and
>   applications both in memory and on your hard disk, and then puts your
>   computer into a low-power state, allowing you to quickly wake the
>   computer and resume your work. The Hybrid Sleep mode is enabled by
>   default in Windows on desktop computers and disabled on laptops. When
>   enabled, it automatically puts your computer into Hybrid Sleep mode
>   when you put it into Sleep mode.
>
> Hybrid Sleep mode is useful for desktop computers in case of a power
>   outage. When power resumes, Windows can restore your work from the
>   hard disk, if the memory is not accessible.
>
> Source: [link](http://www.howtogeek.com/102897/whats-the-difference-between-sleep-and-hibernate-in-windows/)

Answer (score 0):

Your computer actually is NOT shut down. Maybe it's just in sleep mode. You can check in Windows key -> Power Options -> Choose what power buttons do.

Change to whatever you want.