# Monitor turns off quickly in few seconds while windows 10 is still shutting down

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

**Monitor turns off quickly in few seconds while windows 10 is still shutting down**.
Hi everyone ,
I am using Dell OptiPlex 5050 Desktop PC, with Windows 10
Details of the Operating system are
Edition Windows 10 Pro
Version 20H2
Installed on ‎19-‎05-‎2021
OS build 19042.985
Experience Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.2020.0
Details of the PC
Processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700 CPU @ 3.60GHz 3.60 GHz
Installed RAM 8.00 GB (7.88 GB usable)
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Question
I am from the IT department,
In our organization we have 60 Same model PC's. The problem I face is Monitor turns off quickly in few seconds while windows 10 is still shutting down, as soon as the monitor turns off few turn off the power and the Windows OS corrupts, once again we could not use the inbuilt functions like repair PC, we had to install the operating System once again.  But in Laptop, since it is battery powered nothing happens to the OS in the above situation.
I need to keep the monitor stay ON until the windows shuts down like windows 7/XP
I found this command solving my problem

**shutdown.exe /s /t 0**

by using shortcut its possible to do the same,  creating such shortcuts is possible in all computers is possible, but the issues is most of the departments work round the clock, educating all the users to use the shortcut is difficult, if there is a registry edit or so, it might be useful when made default of the shutdown command.

with regards
John

Comment: To my experience the shutdown process always first stops monitor signals and then finishes shut down of Windows 10. Based on your description this is a user problem. Educate your users to check first the power LEDs of the computer before they cut power to the computer (by some switchable multiple socket outlet?).

Comment: I just remembered on option that may help you: Windows uses by default some sort of mini-hibernation mode (kernel hibernation) which is called "fast startup". You could try if disabling Windows 10 fast startup mode is helpful for your problem. You can do so manually https://superuser.com/q/957081/62676 or via Group Policy.