# Windows 11 goes to sleep mode after a long time in lock mode even though I have set "sleep after" to "never" in Power Setup

Tags: windows, sleep, power-management, windows-11

I am running Windows 11. I have set "When plugged in, put my device to sleep after" to be "Never" in Settings > System > Power.

When I lock the screen and leave for a long time, the device still enters some kind of sleep mode. The power LED changes from blue to red and when the device wakes up, I need to input my BitLocker password again. Somehow, it seems my hard drive is put into off mode too.

What causes this? How can I tell Windows to stay awake forever even when the computer is locked? There are some network services running and it should never be off.

[image: screenshot of Power Setup]

Comment: Please run `powercfg /SLEEPSTUDY` and post the file `C:\WINDOWS\system32\sleepstudy-report.html`.

Comment: @Ramhound I think the Login Options doesn't matter for this problem. I use user password to unlock the device. My machine's display does turn off after 10 minutes which is expected. This is a desktop, NOT a laptop. The device box power LED is always blue when it's in the lock state (display off too) but not in the hibernation state. I have put two more comments before your last comment. I found an article about setting hibernate value in Control panel and figured out the default hibernate timeout is 180 minutes. I think by changing the value or changing the plan to High performance will fix it

Comment: @sgon00 - Any significant relevant information should being your question body.  So your question should indicate this is a desktop instead of a comment.  [This](https://superuser.com/questions/957081/how-to-enable-disable-fast-startup-in-windows-10/1532272#1532272) question's answer seems relevant to your issue and thus is likely a duplicate.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for your help. I don't think I need to mention this is a desktop because the problem happened in both desktop and laptop. The problem happened because the `hibernate after` value is not set to Never. So I don't think I need to mention it's a desktop in the question. Sorry that I am new to Windows and use Linux only for my past life. Thank you very much for your patient and help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using the command `powercfg /SLEEPSTUDY` from the help of @harrymc and @Ramhound, I figured out the device entered `Hibernate` STATE with the cause System Idle from the report at `C:\Users\<user>\sleepstudy-report.html`.

By reading [this article](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/enable-or-disable-hibernate-in-windows-11.1894/), it shows how to set the `Hibernate after` value in Control Panel.

Thus the problem happened because Windows 11 **Settings** App does NOT provide a way to turn off `Hibernate after` timeout value. Setting Settings > System > Power > *sleep: never* and *Power mode: Best Performance* will **NOT** change the true Power Plan and will not disable Hibernation.

To turn off the hibernation completely, it has to be done in Control Panel.

Go to ***Control Panel*** > ***System and Security*** > ***Power Options***.

To turn off the hibernation,

1. either change the Plan to `High performance` from additional plans,
2. or Modify the `Hibernate after` value from ***Change plan settings*** for the current plan > ***Change advanced power settings*** > ***Sleep*** > ***Hibernate after***

> *Note that if you change the plan to High performance successfully in Control Panel, The Settings App > System > Power will show a warning message "Power mode can't be set while the high performance plan is used."*

Comment: I knew it was hibernation that was doing it...I didn't remember there being a hibernation setting in the advanced power settings window. Go figure. Surprisingly, you can type the word "never" and press enter, and that's what it sets to (instead of x minutes). This also seems to work for the "turn off hard disk after x minutes" setting. Though I *just* set these, so I have yet to see if Windows interprets the word "never" as *actually* never in these settings, or just as some arbitrary amount of time

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work for me.  In fact I don't even have hibernation as option.  Also, there is **only** a balanced plan.

Comment: It can only be done via the old Control Panel app.

Comment: Thank you! It's such a dumb thing. What's the point of having a misleading settings pannel?

Answer (score 1):

I believe is the following option in 'Edit Power Plan' > 'Change advanced power settings' > 'Sleep' > 'System unattended sleep timeout'

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**************************SOLVED!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!******************************

First go open the run tool and type msconfig then go to the services tab.

Second scroll down disable the Microsoft service labeled "Power" and disable, restart then re-enable it.  Restart one last time.

Lastly I went into the power plan and Restored Default settings.  I decided I am no longer going to use hibernate just sleep.  Tested sleep and worked well.

by doing this it also gave me access to the option to "Turn On fast Startup" in the Define power buttons.. options.

If this does not work also try the steps below.

During my troubleshooting I also tried disabling all services then rebooted.  Then enabled only Microsoft and Intel services, rebooted.  Enabled all services, and then performed the disable power option described above.

Hope this helps everyone, this has been rough when working from home and walking away from my computer for a couple min.